# How to insert apostrophe in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Please help to solved this problem
I am stuck to insert apostrophe in database.
When i fired select query it seems like "It\\'s time to start a new project".

Comment: turn off magic quotes and use prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

'\' is a Escape character, if you are using '\' in query MySQL treats it as a Escape character.
To solve your problem Define a new Escape character by adding "Escape '|' " in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`Prepared Statements`](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and you can stop getting worried about escaping your parameters and stuff. It also helps you wards off against [`SQL Injection Attacks`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).